# Smooth edges on 3D rotating

Tags: css, 3d, css-transforms, antialiasing

I have created a css rotating tetrahedron and now the only thing that prevents me from being happy is that I see that jogged line of the bottom polygon. Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeonly/uxy9x23n/.

Obviously, I want it to be antialiased. And what I have already tried is fixing it with:

- `scale(.9999)`
- adding `padding`
- rotating the bottom polygon in different plans
- setting the color of borders in `rgba`
- creating `outline: 2px solid transparent`

Let me know in case the line is smooth for you. Also, there is a screenshot of that issue when I view it in the latest Chrome: http://imgur.com/nyKKTDb.

Thanks.

Comment: I can see in fact there is antialiasing here but of course it's not enough. The size of the tetrahedron is too small. When the bottom edge is ***nearly parallel*** with the horizonal axis, how could that line be smooth? Even in some 3D scene (in some 3D game), you'll see there is such limitation in rendering. At least we need an extra Full HD screen to render a 1cm line smooth with any angle.

Comment: @King Well, maybe it's a trick of my eyes. Now I have checked, and it's indeed antialiazed. Though not enough. So you suggest to increase the size of tetrahedron?

Comment: I mean with such a small size, the line will be too visibly unsmooth, you should try make it larger and see how it looks better. I'm sure there is not any way to make it look better with the current size (and current angle around X axis).

Comment: @King Ok, thanks. I can mark this as an answer, if you post it so.